# Android - contacts picker , too many results... names only list , how?

Tags: java, android

Here is the code i use to open contacts picker:

```
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

}

How can I open this with only names in contacts list when it opens from intent? Is their flags to add during intent to obtain this display effect when contacts picker starts?

much appreciated. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with the stock intent and contact picker system

Comment: can I kick in the search feature some how after it opens? code?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is actually a way to send in a search query into the contact picker when it's launched. Let me find out.

Comment: Hey, I checked out the activity code and it looks like the text in that search field is grabbed from a string in an xml resource for the contacts app. It doesn't look like you can hijack that. Sorry, that doesn't look possible either.

Comment: what about this: // Use the ContentUris method to produce the base URI for the contact with _ID == 23. Uri myPerson = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, 23); // Alternatively, use the Uri method to produce the base URI. // It takes a string rather than an integer. Uri myPerson = Uri.withAppendedPath(People.CONTENT_URI, "23"); // Then query for this specific record: Cursor cur = managedQuery(myPerson, null, null, null, null); seems you can inject the picker before it starts! Why not set it to display all names???

Comment: Are you suggesting using that URI instead of Contacts.CONTENT_URI? If so, I don't think it will work. That intent won't be filtered by the contact picker.